# Cron Expression 1010

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

i need cron expression for to schedule job for every 2min.

I tried

```
String Cron = '0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *';
```

but throwing exception like the sec and min cron expression should be in integer only.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this through a single Cron expression. Salesforce allows at most one execution per hour per scheduled job.

Your only options will be to create 30 separate scheduled jobs or schedule the next job in your finish method. Keep in mind that each org can only have at most 100 scheduled jobs at a time.